# Group values for groupby().mean()

Tags: python, pandas, group

Have a Dataframe:

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 1 | 52 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 4 | 67 |
| 1 | 34 |
| 3 | 112 |
| 5 | 55 |
| 4 | 33 |
| 5 | 87 |
| 1 | 108 |

Looking to create 2 groups from Column_A, and find the average of those groups in Column_B:

So first group might be 1, 2 and 3, second group 4 and 5.

I get the basics behind groupby()

```
df.groupby("Column_A")["Column_B"].mean()
```

and calling certain values in columns

```
df[df["Column_A"] == 1].groupby()[].mean()
```

But is there a way to include the group of (1, 2 and 3) and (4, 5) from Column_A? Somehow doing:

```
[["Column_A"] == 1, 2, 3].groupby(Column_B).mean()
```

And:

```
[["Column_A"] == 4, 5].groupby(Column_B).mean()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: check `.isin` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Looking to create 2 groups from Column_A, and find the average of those groups in Column_B

You can use a condition in groupby for the items in [1, 2, 3] vs. not in the list i.e. [4, 5].

```
df.groupby(df['Column_A'].isin([1, 2, 3]))['Column_B'].mean()

Output:
Column_A
False    60.500000
True     53.285714
Name: Column_B, dtype: float64
```

> what if i wanted to find the .count() of Column_B = 25 under the same isin conditions

```
# Is this what you wanted?
df.groupby(df['Column_A'].isin([1, 2, 3]) & (df['Column_B']==25))['Column_B'].count()

Output:
False    10
True      1
Name: Column_B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. I'd upvote but don't have the rep yet. what if i wanted to find the .count() of Column_B = 25 under the same isin conditions, for example? I think im putting brackets in the wrong place.

Comment: @MB2000 1) does the updated answer help?  2) you can accept an answer even if you don't have the rep to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `cut` to bin the first column, then `groupby.mean`:

```
(df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Column_A'], [0,3,5], labels=['1-3', '4-5']))
   ['Column_B'].mean()
 )
```

Output:

```
Column_A
1-3    53.285714
4-5    60.500000
Name: Column_B, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df["Column_A"] <= 3].groupby("Column_A")["Column_B"].mean()
df[df["Column_A"] > 3].groupby("Column_A")["Column_B"].mean()
```

if `Column_A` is not numeric, use `isin`

Answer (score 0):

Using `isin` if you only want a specific values group (1,2,3 and 4,5)

```
df[df["Column_A"].isin([1,2,3])].groupby("Column_A")["Column_B"].mean()
df[df["Column_A"].isin([4,5])].groupby("Column_A")["Column_B"].mean()
```

[isin doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)